# Looking for a (short or novel length) story where the narrator is to perform a surgery giving a man bionic eyes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read the story over five years ago now (so my memory of it isn't very good), and it's killing me that I can't find it anywhere online. I'm all so not totally sure if it was a short story or just a piece taken from a larger work.

It was told from the point of view of a doctor who has to perform a surgery to give a young man bionic eyes much like she had. The reason for the enhancement had some thing to do with the planet they were going to. She kinda lamented the loss of humanity with removing eyes and replacing them with soulless dark lenses. She disliked her own, and pitied the the young man who was to have the enhancement.

Ring any bells for anyone?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: This reminds me a bit of Segregationist by Asimov, though that was an old man not a young man, a replacement heart not eyes, and the surgeon was a robot not a human. Apart from that it's a perfect match :-)